# prolog sort and print best 3

Tags: sorting, prolog

what I have now is,

```
   :-dynamic listofPeople/2.
    listofPeople(Mark,Name).
```

e.g.

```
     19, 'Jos'
     92, 'Abdul'
     33, 'Izz'
     16, 'Xin'
```

I want it like this -

```
92, 'Abdul'
33, 'Izz'
19, 'Jos'
```

which basiclly contains the mark for each student.

I want to print the best 3 marks.

To do that, I blv I have to do sorting. If I do sorting, I will lose the order of the name of the student.

As you can understand by default, what I want is to sort only the marks and change the names position according to the marks as well, so when i print

i get the above output

Code snippets appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: you have a collection of facts, like listOfPeople(19,'Jos'), and you want to print those with the top 3 marks, sorted by name?

Comment: that is right, I have a collection of names with marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered you in a thread below:

```
go(N1-G1,N2-G2,N3-G3) :- findall(Grade-Name, listofPeople(Grade,Name), List), 
                         keysort(List, [G1-N1,G2-N2,G3-N3|SortedList]).
```

On your input `go(X,Y,Z)` results in `X = 'Abdul'-92, Y = 'Izz'-33, Z ='Jos'-19`.

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, no one was answering my question, so I asked again in more detail. Could you please take a look at my another problem please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437395/prolog-how-to-assert-make-a-database-only-once

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you sort the list by mark, take the top 3, and then sort THAT by name, before you print?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. Sort the list by mark. How do I do that.

My problem is, there are 2 data types, int-String. How do I sort the int part only?

Comment: How would you do it if it were a list of integers?

Comment: sort(Input, Output).
but over here I need to link the marks with respective names, hence can't do. :(