# Prolog - How to assert/make a database only once

Tags: prolog, rule

```
resultList(UsersQuery):-
    question(X,H),
    write(H),
    myintersection(H,UsersQuery,Match,TotalQuestionKeywords),
    Percent is Match/TotalQuestionKeywords*100,
    write('Question: '),
    write(X),nl,write('Quality: '), write(Percent),write('%'),nl,

    /* please look at this part
    Percent>=50,
    assert(listofQuestions(Percent,Question)),
    write(Percent),write(Question),nl,
    fail.
resultList(_).
```

I want to populate a fact database named 'listofQuestions'. Everything works fine, but the stuffs that I am asserting stays in the memory. So, if I run my program again, I get the same bunch of facts added to the 'listofQuestions'.

I only want to have one set of data.

Thankyou

Comment: try using the if-then-else built-in predicate `( listofQuestions(P,Q) -> true ; assert(listofQuestions(P,Q)) )`

Comment: that works kind of fine. But what I would want is a fresh blank "listofQuestions" everytime I would call my rule. It only happens if I restart prolog. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe do `retractall/1` before you rerun your program.

Comment: Thanks very much. I did have a retractall statement later on. But reading your comment I placed it one line before. And it works as a peach! xD

Answer (score 3):

Make a separate predicate for assertion that checks if fact is not yet asserted:

```
assertThisFact(Fact):-
    \+( Fact ),!,         % \+ is a NOT operator.
    assert(Fact).
assertThisFact(_).
```

Comment: I like this answer. Is this concept bullet proof? What about this `not`, is it `swi-prolog` compatible?

Comment: Alternatively, in a single clause and without negation: `assert_once(Fact) :-
        ( Fact, !
        ; assertz(Fact) ).`