# Prolog - Assert into a new database

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

```
:-dynamic listofQuestions/2.
myrule:-
    write('P = '), write(Percent), write('-'),write(X),
    ( listofQuestions(Percent,X) -> true ; assert(listofQuestions(Percent,X)) ),
```

The code snippet might not be required to answer my question.

I want to assert to a blank 'listofQuestions' everytime I call my rule. This only happens if I close my prolog window and restart it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog - How to assert/make a database only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437395/prolog-how-to-assert-make-a-database-only-once)

Comment: Maybe, because that question was asked by me as well. I need to wipe whatever it was stored everytime my program exits. It satisfies what I need, everytime PROLOG exits. But that isn't what I need. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abolish/1` removes all clauses of a given predicate from the database. Hence, just add a call to `abolish(PredName/Arity)` whenever you need to remove the information about this predicate. Beware that after abolishing the call to the dynamic predicate does not fail but reports an error.

```
12 ?- f(X,Y).
false.

13 ?- assert(f(a,b)).
true.

14 ?- f(X,Y).
X = a,
Y = b.

15 ?- abolish(f/2).
true.

16 ?- f(X,Y).
ERROR: user://2:67:
        toplevel: Undefined procedure: f/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

In SWI-Prolog, `abolish` works on static procedures, unless the prolog flag `iso` is set to true. If you intend to remove only dynamic predicates, you should better try `retractall`. Observe that in this case removal does not lead to an error being reported but to a failure.

```
17 ?- [user].
:- dynamic f/2.
|: 
% user://3 compiled 0.00 sec, 264 bytes
true.

18 ?- f(X,Y).
false.

19 ?- assert(f(a,b)).
true.

20 ?- f(X,Y).
X = a,
Y = b.

21 ?- retractall(f(X,Y)).
true.

22 ?- f(X,Y).
false.
```